# Could anybody please help me to rewrite this code using useEffect()?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Here's the code. I'm still very new to using functional components.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
  }

  if (nextProps.errors) {
    this.setState({
      errors: nextProps.errors,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And since you are using `this.`, is it a class or a functional component?

Comment: we need a fully reproducible example. also please show what error you are getting

Comment: It was initially written using a class component. But now now I'm trying to convert it to a functional component. I'm trying to enable users login into their account. This authenticating them to see if they their details are correct in the database. And if correct, direct them to their dashboards.

Comment: @jonathan Alfaro. I'm not getting an error per se. I just want to know how to rewrite this.

Comment: There is a policy in stackoverflow. We dont write your code for you.  We only help you when you bump into trouble. So we need to see what you have already tried.  You need to provide a fully reproducible example along with the current outcome and the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

To convert this class component into functional component, you will need `useState()` hook for the errors' state variable, `useHistory()` for the `history` and `useEffect()` for the main logic.

1. Getting props and extracting required data:

   ```
    const {auth, errors} = nextProps; //Destructuring the object
   ```
2. Declaring state variable for errors:

   ```
    //assuming its an array, setting empty array as default/initial value
    const [localErrors, setLocalErrors] = useState([]);
   ```
3. Declaring history variable to push/pop pages:

   ```
    const history = useHistory();
   ```
4. Finally, declaring the useEffect():

   ```
    //Adding auth and errors as dependencies to listen for changes
    //and run this code whenever any change occurs.
    //Remove them if useEffect should only be run first time
    useEffect(() => {
      if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
        history.push("/dashboard"); //changing page
      }
      if (errors) {
        setLocalErrors(errors); //updating state
      }
    }, [
    auth,
    errors
    ]); //Adding dependencies as an array
   ```

Optional: You can attach a return callback to the `useEffect` to detach any listeners or clean up when the component unmounts as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).